# Error in python code - SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Tags: python

I need to use a code written by someone else in Python a while back, and I get a `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` in this line:

```
tfileServices = {n: s.fileName for n, s in process.services.iteritems() if s.type_() == 'TFileService'}
```

I am not really sure what is wrong about it, so can someone tell me why is it not working (it supposedly worked for him)? Thank you! (I am not sure what to google for to find out what is wrong, as I am not sure how the actual syntax should look like)

Comment: which version of python are you using? dictionary comprehensions didn't exist in 2.6 ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre introduced in 2.7

Comment: I have closed the question. your syntax is OK, but you have to adapt your code. not very difficult.

Comment: I have 2.6.6 actually...

Comment: @Bobo This is the problem. As Jean-François Fabre suggested, dictionary comprehension is  only available from 2.7

Comment: I have added a link to help you transpose your code to 2.6

Comment: @Bobo : `dict((n, s.fileName) for n, s in process.services.iteritems() if s.type_() == 'TFileService')`